# Converting VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

i have found a theme for my c# .net project, but the theme is in VB.I have tried to convert it using codefusion and other online converters, but without success, I also tried to manually convert it but i get more than 500 errors so i believe i am doing something wrong.
Could anybody help me convert these components to C#?
Here is the link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25995914/Flat%20UI(v.1.0.4).vb

Here is a link to my conversion with alot of errors. http://pastebin.com/FXb344qH

Comment: I just did this the other day. It was fairly easy. VB is like pseudo code, to me anyway. So rather than convert it I read the VB code and re-write it in C#. The important parts which are highlighted (VS) show the .NET framework which is the same in both languages.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen a theme from HF make its way to SO.

Comment: @ByteBlast, what does "HF" mean?

Comment: Acronym for HackForums. http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=3559385

Comment: @ByteBlast, OK, thanks, I guess I'm leading a too sheltered life.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service.

Comment: Good:  You posted code and showed what you had tried.  Bad:  You posted almost 4,000 lines of code with a few lines commented as to an error.   Try updating your question to just the parts that are relevant - post a snippet of the VB.NET code and the C# conversion you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the VB.NET code as a class library (.dll), and then reference the class library in your C# project.